# Where can the DNA splicers be obtained and how is it used?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In Pokemon X/Y, where/how can you obtain the DNA splicers and how exactly do you use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DNA Splicer can only be obtained after a few requirements are met.

•   You must have first beat the Elite Four and have gone to Kiloude City

•   You must have the Pokemon Bank app on your 3DS

•   You must have transferred over Kyurem, Reshiram and/or Zekrom from B/W(2) through the Pokemon Bank

Once you have completed these first steps, go to Kiloude City. Make sure you have Kyurem in your party. Go to the northwestern part of the city where there are 2 houses next to each other, go inside the one on the right. Inside there will be a “punk” looking girl. Talk to her and after a brief dialogue sequence, you will receive the DNA Splicer and will be placed in your key items bag.

[image]

To use the DNA Splicer:

•   Put Kyurem in your party

•   Put Reshiram or Zekrom in your party

Go to your key items menu and select the DNA Splicer, once you use it, it will ask you which Pokemon you want to fuse. First select Kyurem and then select the other legendary dragon in your party. Those 2 will start to show a little swirl icon and will be combined into one Pokemon. To get the Pokemon back to normal, you would simply just select the DNA Splicer from your menu again, and this time select only Kyurem. It will then un-fuse back to the original 2 dragons.

[image]

Comment: Very good answer, except for one thing. You don't _need_ to have pokemon bank if you have obtained the necessary pokemon through trading.

Answer (score -2):

First, have Kyurem in your party and talk to the lady in one of the houses in Kiloude City, and she will give you DNA splicers. Afterwards click "use" on the splicers and click on Kyurem and then Reshiram/Zekrom.